# filled textfield value from select dropdown with split()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, split

when i use split() the textfield value is empty, value for textfield from drop down that i need is e.g 15.
please show me where did i go wrong..
thanks,

here's the code :

```
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems">
    <option value="price1:15">blue</option>
    <option value="price2:20">green</option>
    <option value="price3:25">red</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice" onClick="checkPrice()">

var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems');
var pecah = select.split(":");
var hasil = pecah[1];

var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
select.onchange = function() {
    input.value = hasil.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<select name="cmbitems" id="cmbitems">
    <option value="price1:15">blue</option>
    <option value="price2:20">green</option>
    <option value="price3:25">red</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="txtprice" id="txtprice">

var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems');
select.onchange = function() {
        var pecah = select.options;
        var hasil = pecah[pecah.selectedIndex];
    input.value = hasil.value.split(":")[1];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var input = document.getElementById('txtprice');
document.getElementById('cmbitems').onchange = function() {
var select = document.getElementById('cmbitems').value;
var pecah = select.split(":");
var hasil = pecah[1];
alert(hasil);
input.value = hasil;
}
```